# if null on mysql not showing using JOIN TABLE

Tags: mysql

table tb_order

```
CREATE TABLE tb_order(
  id_order INT,
  id_pecahan INT,
  no_order INT,
  seri VARCHAR(55),
  tahun YEAR,
  id_target INT
);

INSERT INTO tb_order VALUES
(1, 1, 121, 'GH-C6',2023,1),
(2, 2, 256, 'YZ-D2',2023,2),
(3, 3 , 151, 'LM-C9',2023,3);
```

| id_order | id_pecahan | no_order | seri | tahun | id_target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 121 | GH-C6 | 2023 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 256 | YZ-D2 | 2023 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 151 | LM-C9 | 2023 | 3 |

table tb_pecahan

```
CREATE TABLE tb_pecahan(
  id_pecahan INT,
  pecahan VARCHAR(55),
  bilyet INT
);

INSERT INTO tb_pecahan VALUES
(1, 's', 45),
(2, 't', 45),
(3, 'u', 45),
(4, 'v', 45),
(5, 'w', 45),
(6, 'x', 45),
(7, 'y' , 45);
```

| id_pecahan | pecahan | bilyet |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | s | 45 |
| 2 | t | 45 |
| 3 | u | 45 |
| 4 | v | 45 |
| 5 | w | 45 |
| 6 | x | 45 |
| 7 | y | 45 |

table tb_target

```
CREATE TABLE tb_target(
  id_target INT,
  id_pecahan INT,
  target INT,
  tahun YEAR,
  insit DECIMAL(10,2)
);

INSERT INTO tb_target VALUES
(1,1, 70000000, 2023,4.90),
(2,2, 60000000, 2023,5.75),
(3,3, 50000000, 2023,5.75),
(4,4, 40000000, 2023,7.15),
(5,5, 30000000, 2023,7.15),
(6,6, 20000000, 2023,7.20),
(7,7, 10000000 , 2023,6.96);
```

| id_target | id_pecahan | target | tahun | inschiet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 70000000 | 2023 | 4.90 |
| 2 | 2 | 60000000 | 2023 | 5.75 |
| 3 | 3 | 50000000 | 2023 | 5.75 |
| 4 | 4 | 40000000 | 2023 | 7.15 |
| 5 | 5 | 30000000 | 2023 | 7.15 |
| 6 | 6 | 20000000 | 2023 | 7.20 |
| 7 | 7 | 10000000 | 2023 | 6.96 |

table tb_*cutpack*_detail

```
CREATE TABLE tb_cutpack_detail(
  id INT,
  tanggal DATE,
  id_order INT,
  good INT
);

INSERT INTO tb_cutpack_detail VALUES
(1,'2023-02-22', 2, 10000),
(2,'2023-02-22', 3, 5000),
(3,'2023-02-22', 1 , 35000);
```

| id | tanggal | id_order | good |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-02-22 | 2 | 10000 |
| 2 | 2023-02-22 | 3 | 5000 |
| 3 | 2023-02-22 | 1 | 35000 |

table tb_mutasi

```
CREATE TABLE tb_mutasi(
  id INT,
  tanggal DATE,
  id_order INT,
  good INT
);

INSERT INTO tb_mutasi VALUES
(1,'2023-02-22', 3, 4000),
(2,'2023-02-22', 1, 6000),
(3,'2023-02-22', 2 , 11000);
```

| id | tanggal | id_order | good |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-02-23 | 3 | 4000 |
| 2 | 2023-02-23 | 1 | 6000 |
| 3 | 2023-02-23 | 2 | 11000 |

I've done this

```
SELECT d.pecahan,e.insit,d.bilyet,e.target,SUM(COALESCE(b.baik,0))+SUM(COALESCE(c.baikb,0)) jumlah
FROM tb_order a
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT id_order ,SUM(COALESCE(good,0)) baik 
        FROM  tb_cutpack_detail 
        GROUP BY id_order)  b  USING(id_order)
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT id_order ,SUM(COALESCE(good,0)) baikb
        FROM  tb_mutasi 
        GROUP BY id_order)  c  USING(id_order)
    LEFT JOIN tb_pecahan d USING(id_pecahan)
    LEFT JOIN tb_target e USING(id_target)
WHERE  a.tahun=2023 
GROUP BY d.pecahan,e.insit,e.target,d.bilyet 
ORDER BY d.pecahan
```

the result is like this..

the results are only from row s to u..I want it to appear from s to y.. is that possible for me

| pecahan | insit | bilyet | target | jumlah |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| s | 4.90 | 45 | 70000000 | 41000 |
| t | 5.75 | 45 | 60000000 | 21000 |
| u | 5.75 | 45 | 50000000 | 9000 |

I want the fraction columns that are in tb_target from the s to y fraction columns to all appear...

Or is there really no solution?

thank you

I want my final results to look like this:

| pecahan | insit | bilyet | target | jumlah |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| s | 4.90 | 45 | 70000000 | 41000 |
| t | 5.75 | 45 | 60000000 | 21000 |
| u | 5.75 | 45 | 50000000 | 9000 |
| v | 7.15 | 45 | 40000000 | NULL |
| w | 7.15 | 45 | 30000000 | NULL |
| x | 7.20 | 45 | 20000000 | NULL |
| y | 6.96 | 45 | 10000000 | NULL |

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Comment: Getting all the records from tb_pecaham would require making tb_pecaham the first table in the list or doing a right join to it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is posible, but then you have to modify the LEFT JOIN with a RIGHT JOIN for the table tb_pecahan

```
SELECT d.pecahan,e.insit,d.bilyet,e.target,SUM(COALESCE(b.baik,0))+SUM(COALESCE(c.baikb,0)) jumlah
FROM tb_order a
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT id_order ,SUM(COALESCE(baik + PARTIAL + hasil_unfit_rework,0)) baik 
        FROM  tb_cutpack_detail 
        GROUP BY id_order)  b  USING(id_order)
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT id_order ,SUM(COALESCE(baik + PARTIAL + hasil_unfit_rework,0)) baikb
        FROM  tb_cutpackb_siap_detail 
        GROUP BY id_order)  c  USING(id_order)
    RIGHT JOIN tb_pecahan d USING(id_pecahan)
    LEFT JOIN tb_target e USING(id_target)
WHERE a.tahun = 2023 
GROUP BY d.pecahan,e.insit,e.target,d.bilyet 
ORDER BY d.pecahan
```

In that way, you will recover all rows from table tb_pecahan

Comment: it doesn't work sir, the result is the same as my question

Comment: Can it be changed according to your wishes regarding this case?

Comment: You should also remove the where a.tahun=2023 and set where a.tahun=2023 or a.tahun is null

Comment: thank you for the answer... after I tried it, it worked, but it only brought up fractional rows from s to y... but the input and target were still NULL. Is it still possible for me to solve my problem?@nacho

Comment: how to fix this case?
@easleyfixed

Comment: Does it maybe need parathesis ? ( e a.tahun=2023 or a.tahun is null ) ?

Comment: your answer is the same as the answer above @nacho....